# NodeJS Performance with working with arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to retrieve a user's chats with corresponding users from a different collection in NodeJS and MongoDB.
The nature of NodeJS gives me a bad feeling that running the following code will block or decrease performance of my app. I can duplicate some data but I want to learn more about NodeJS.

Please let me know whether my code is ok and will not decrease performance.

Here I fetch 20 chats. I also need their corresponding users.
then I get the `userIds` and perform another query against the `User` collection.
Now I have both but I should merge them using `Array.map`.

I don't use `$lookup` because my collections are sharded.

> **$lookup**
>
> Performs a left outer join to an unsharded collection in the same database to filter in documents from the "joined" collection for processing. To each input document, the $lookup stage adds a new array field whose elements are the matching documents from the "joined" collection. The $lookup stage passes these reshaped documents to the next stage.
> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-lookup

```js
let chats = await Chat.find({ active: true }).limit(20);
/*
[
  {_id: ..., userId: 1, title: 'Chat A'},
  ...
]
*/


const userIds = chats.map(item => item.userId);
/*
[1, ...]
*/


const users = await User.find({ _id: { $in: userIds }});
/*
[
  {_id: 1, fullName: 'Jack'},
  ...
]
*/


chats = chats.map(item => {
  item.user = users.find(user => user._id === item.userId);

  return item;
});
/*
[
  {
    _id: ...,
    userId: 1,
    user: {_id: 1, fullName: 'Jack'},    // <-------- added
    title: 'Chat A'
  },
  ...
]
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is NOT how you should do it. MongoDB has something called Aggregation Framework and [$lookup pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) that will do that for you automatically with only 1 MongoDB query.

But since you are using Mongoose, this query become even more simpler since you can use `populate()` method of the Mongoose. So your whole code can be replaced with one line like this:

```js
const chats = await Chat.find({ active: true }).populate('userId').limit(20);

console.log(chats);
```

---

**Note:** If your collections are sharded, in my opinion you already implemented the logic in best possible way.

Comment: My collections are sharded no chance for $lookup.

Comment: I see. You should add that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are using async/await, so your code will wait a response from every time use `await`

```
// Wait to finish here
let chats = await Chat.find({ active: true }).limit(20);
/*
[
  {_id: ..., userId: 1, title: 'Chat A'},
  ...
]
*/

// Wait to finish here too
const users = await User.find({ _id: { $in: userIds }});
/*
[
  {_id: 1, fullName: 'Jack'},
  ...
]
*/
```

So if you has too many data and you don't have any index on your collection it will be too long to finish those query.
At this case you should create `ref` in your collection `Chat` to collection `User` with chat.userId = user._id

Then when you call query chat, you `populate` field `userId` so you don't have to map `const userIds = chats.map(item => item.userId);` and `chats = chats.map...`

Sample for chat schema

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");

const chatSchema = new Schema({
  active: Boolean,
  userId: {
    type: "ObjectId",
    ref: "User",
  },
  title: String,
  message: String
  // another property
});

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  email: String
  // another property
})


// query for chat

const chatModel = new model('chat', chatSchema)
let chats = await chatModel.find({ active: true }).populate('userId').limit(20);

/*
[
  {
    _id: ...,
    userId: {_id: 1, fullName: 'Jack'},    // <-------- already have
    title: 'Chat A'
  },
  ...
]
*/
```

Comment: The `populate` method does the same behind the scene but with less code exposed to programmers. Please read: https://medium.com/cameoeng/mongodb-lookups-and-populates-an-unexpected-journey-940e08e36a94